# Problem with implementing stripe in multi vender website using custom connected account in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments

I have a wordpress website multi site to be specific and i want to implement custom connected account for each vendor..

i am using woocommerce and woocommerce stripe gatway for payments it all works fine but the problem comes in when i am transfering money to connected account.

i am using the below function for transfering money to a connected account but the problem is that when an order is placed and payment is made it goes to pending balance and now i am not able to pay to connected account because i don't have balance and its in pending so how can tackle the issue..

is there some way that i can split the payment before a payment is made main account or is there some way i can send the pending balance to my connected account... any help would be appreciated...

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_split_payment', 10, 1);

function custom_split_payment($order_id) {

    // Get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Check if the order is paid
    if ($order->is_paid()) {
        // Get the payment method used
        $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

        // Check if the payment method is Stripe
        if ($payment_method === 'stripe') {

            // Get the Stripe customer ID associated with the order
            $customer_id = $order->get_meta('_stripe_customer_id', true);

            $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
            $connected_account_id = get_site_option('vendor_stripe_id_' . $blog_id);

            // Get the order total
            $order_total = $order->get_total();

            $stripe_api_keys = get_site_option('stripe_api_keys');

            $key = '';

            if( isset( $stripe_api_keys["test_mode"] )  ) {
                if( isset($stripe_api_keys['test_secret_key']) ){
                    $key = $stripe_api_keys['test_secret_key'];
                }
            } else if ( isset( $stripe_api_keys['live_secret_key'] ) ) {
                $key = $stripe_api_keys['live_secret_key'];
            }

            $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($key);
            $commission_key = 'vendor_commission_percentage_' . $blog_id;

            $commission_percentage = get_site_option($commission_key);

            $commission_amount = number_format($order_total * ($commission_percentage / 100), 2);

            $array = [
                'amount' => $commission_amount * 100,  // Amount in cents
                'currency' => 'usd',  // Change currency as needed
                'destination' => $connected_account_id,
            ];

            try {
                // Your Stripe API call here
                $stripe->transfers->create($array);

                // Additional code if the API call is successful

            } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
                // This block will be executed if there is an API error
                echo 'Stripe API Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                // You can handle the exception here, log the error, or take appropriate actions

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // This block will be executed for other exceptions not specific to Stripe
                echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                // Handle other exceptions here

            } finally {
                // This block will be executed regardless of whether an exception occurred or not
                // You can include cleanup code or additional actions that need to be performed
            }

            die();

            $stripe->transfers->create($array);

            $order->update_status('processing');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you would want to do when creating the Transfer is to include the corresponding Charge id in the `source_transaction` parameter : https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create#create_transfer-source_transaction

The main point to remember is that when using `source_transaction`, if the payment is still pending, then the transfer will pull the funds from the pending balance. If the payment is already available, then the transfer will pull the funds from the available balance.

if you don't specify the `source_transaction`, it'll always try to use the funds from your available balance and if the payment funds is not yet available, and you don't specify the `source_transaction` then you may run into the problem of insufficient funds.